# Android system keeps resetting default USB configuration upon PC connection

Tags: usb, charging, usb-connection-mode, system, system-apps

Whenever I'm connecting my Samsung Galaxy A40 running Android 9.0 to a laptop or PC, I'm getting an annoying prompt to allow data transfer, and the following setting which I had set to "Charging phone only" gets reset to "Transferring files":

[image]

However, I only want to charge the phone and absolutely never allow data transfer for security reasons as I frequently have to connect my phone to public or workplace PCs for charging. The service which throws the notification/prompt is called *Android System* and the icon looks a bit like this (only with filled font):

[image: Android System]

I activated developer options and explicitly configured the USB connection settings to **not** allow data transfer. Why does *Android System* keep changing my settings and prompting for data transfer? Is this normal behaviour? Is there a way to regain control without having to root the device?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105646/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-david).

Comment: Dammit, I wish this happened for me! Trying to figure out a way to freeze the setting at *MTP file transfer* (which keeps getting reset to *Charge only* :(

Comment: Haha. The funny thing is that now my setting is also on *Charge Only* as default and I have no idea when or how this changed

Answer (score 0):

FIX (may help someone): it's not a software issue, you just have to clean your charging port as it shows in the following video: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/KRkwcLKz3IA.
Also remember that you must have developers options and usb debugging enabled.
This worked for me.